# Invoking zmv from bash

Tags: shell, zsh, quoting, rename

I have recently discovered this technique for renaming files using `zsh`:

```
autoload zmv
zmv '(*).JPG' '$1.jpg'
```

which I can also write as:

```
autoload zmv; zmv '(*).JPG' '$1.jpg'
```

This works as advertised and I can use it to change the Upper Case `JPG` extension to lower case.

However, I would like to run this as a one-liner from my usual BASH shell. When I try to call it as follows:

```
zsh -c "autoload zmv; zmv -f '(*).JPG' '$1.jpg'"
```

or as:

```
echo 'autoload zmv; zmv -f "(*).JPG" "$1.jpg"' | zsh -i
```

I get something like the following message

```
zmv: error(s) in substitution:
….JPG and ….JPG both map to .jpg
```

This suggests to me that that `zsh` is treating the file names case-insensitively, but that does not appear to be the case when run the first way.

Obviously, I don’t know what I’m doing here. I have also tried reversing the single and double quotes in case shell expansion is getting in the way.

How can I run this command as a one-liner from bash?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In:

```
zsh -c "autoload zmv; zmv -f '(*).JPG' '$1.jpg'"
```

The `$1` is between double quotes, so expanded by your shell (`bash`), most probably to the empty string so `zsh` ends up interpreting:

```
autoload zmv; zmv -f '(*).JPG' '.jpg'
```

Use:

```
zsh -c "autoload zmv && zmv '(*).JPG' '\$1.jpg'"
```

Where the backslash *quotes* the `$` for `bash` to remove its special meaning inside double quotes.

You can also do:

```
zsh -c "autoload zmv && zmv '(*).(#i)jpg' '\$1.jpg'"
```

Where `(#i)` is to turn on case-insensitive matching so it also renames the `.Jpg`, `.JPg`, `.jpG`... files.

You could also make it a function:

```
fix_ext_case() {
  EXT=$1 zsh -c "autoload zmv && zmv \"(*).(#i)\$EXT\" '\$1.\$EXT'"
}
```

Or with a different combination of quotes:

```
fix_ext_case() {
  EXT=$1 zsh -c 'autoload zmv && zmv "(*).(#i)$EXT" "\$1.\$EXT"'
}
```

To be used as:

```
fix_ext_case jpg
```

or

```
fix_ext_case png
```

(or `fix_ext_case JPG` if you want to convert to upper-case).

Comment: Excellent. The `\` did the trick. Thanks also for your additional information.