# Are there ways to use zmv, zcalc, zparseopts and other zsh built-in utilities inside bash?

Tags: bash, zsh

I have been using `bash` for years and would like to stay with it.  But at the same time, there are utilities in `zsh` that are nice to use.  Are there ports so those commands like `zmv`, `zcalc` or `zparseopts` live as individual `/bin` executables?  Or I have to use tricks like [this](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/400801/419446)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The strength of `zsh`'s `zmv` resides in `zsh`'s immensely superior globbing and parameter expansion operators. A similar `bmv` that would be limited to `bash`'s globbing and parameter expansion operators would be nowhere as useful as `zsh`'s `zmv`.

And if you had a `zmv` for `bash` that was using `zsh`-like operators, you'd still have to learn those, and would then be frustrated when using `bash` where you could not use those advanced operators for the rest.

In any case, you can always do the latter in `bash` with:

```
zmv() {
  zsh -c 'autoload zmv && zmv "$@"' zmv "$@"
}

zcalc() {
  zsh -c 'autoload zcalc && zcalc "$@"' zcalc "$@"
}
```

Which define `zmv` and `zcalc` as functions that run the corresponding `zsh` function within a new invocation of the `zsh` interpreter.

Note however that it's limited in that those functions don't have access to the internal variables of your `bash` shell obviously.

For instance, if you do `pi = 4 * atan(1)` in that `zcalc`, that `$pi` variable won't be available in your `bash` shell afterwards.

For that same reason, taking that approach for `zparseopts` would be completely useless.